# SNMP4J How Mock a GETBULK Request?

Tags: java, mocking, snmp, snmp4j

I need to mock a GETBULK request with snmp4j in java. But I don't understand how to do it. More specific i don't understand how create TreeEvent for create response List and how answer to client.

I've a snmpwalk like this

```
public void sendWalk(String community, String ipAddress, int port, String oidValue, int retries, long timeoutMillis) throws IOException {

    CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
    comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
    comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
    comtarget.setRetries(retries);
    comtarget.setTimeout(timeoutMillis);
    comtarget.setVersion(snmpVersion);


    OID oid = new OID(oidValue);

    TreeUtils treeUtils = new TreeUtils(snmp, new DefaultPDUFactory());
    List<TreeEvent> events = treeUtils.walk(comtarget, new OID[]{oid});
    if(events == null || events.size() == 0) {
        // TODO inserire in allarm manager ???
        log.warn(" No events . Request[Oid:"+oidValue+"]");
    }else{
        parseWalkResult(events);
    }

}
```

A snmpwalk on SNMP4J is a GETBULK request, then i want to implement a mock to response at treeUtils.walk method and have List of TreeEvents as answer from mockup.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNMP4j to do SNMPBULKWALK on the router. SNMP4j provides below API to retrieve entire subtree of a given rootnode synchronously.

Class: TreeUtils.java Method: getSubtree(targetV2, rootOID);

It also provides another method which is asynchronous.

Class: TreeUtils.java Method: walk(targetV2, rootOIDs);

I have a github project which has the complete working code. You can clone the [github repo](https://github.com/jineshmathewt/snmpbulkwalk) and try it.